# Rank displaying for all user fine. But how do I display rank for one user?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY s.rows DESC) AS Ranks,
    Territory, TM_Name,
    COALESCE(g.rows, 0) AS RXCount, 
    COALESCE(s.rows, 0) AS DelCounts,
    COALESCE(nd.rows, 0) AS NotDeliveredCount,
    COALESCE(trgt.rows, 0) AS Target,
    e.TM_Emp_Id
FROM 
    tblEmployee e
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT EmpCode, SUM(RxGenerate) AS rows 
     FROM tbl_RX 
     GROUP BY EmpCode) g ON g.EmpCode = e.TM_Emp_Id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT EmpCode, SUM(MedToPCount) AS rows 
     FROM tbl_MedicinToPatient 
     WHERE Status = 'Delivered' 
     GROUP BY EmpCode) s ON s.EmpCode = e.TM_Emp_Id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT EmpCode, COUNT(*) AS rows 
     FROM tbl_MedicinToPatient 
     WHERE Status != 'Delivered' 
     GROUP BY EmpCode) nd ON nd.EmpCode = e.TM_Emp_Id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         EmpCode, CurrentTarget AS rows,   
         CreatedDate, RankOrder, T.PreviousTarget 
     FROM
         (SELECT
              EmpCode, CurrentTarget, CreatedDate,PreviousTarget,
              RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpCode ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) RankOrder
          FROM
              tbl_Target) T 
     WHERE 
         RankOrder = 1) trgt ON trgt.EmpCode = e.TM_Emp_Id
```

It returns the desired output. That is for every user it calculates rank perfectly. But when I add where condition in the end of query such as:

```
e.TM_Emp_Id = 101
```

It display a rank of 1. And for every user I get the same result (i.e. Rank 1).
But I want to display original rank. How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: wrap your query `select * from (your code) t where t.TM_Emp_Id=101`

Comment: Spot on thanks mate! @JamieD77 Do give me answer so that I accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least 3 easy options for this.

1. Encapsulate the whole query into a subquery so that it looks like

   ```
   select * 
   from (current code) 
   where TM_Emp_ID = 101
   ```
2. Same as above except make it a CTE:

   ```
   WITH MY_QUERY AS 
   (current code) 
   SELECT * 
   FROM MY_QUERY 
   WHERE TM_EMP_ID = 101
   ```
3. same as both the 2 above except use a temp table

Answer (score 1):

You must rank all users in order to know the rank of a particaular user. So select from your query:

```
select *
from ( your query here ) q
where tm_emp_id = 101;
```